# SmartGit crash in ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, jre, crash

When I try select repository application crash. It's perhaps bug

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/java-common/+bug/1241101

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with ubuntu 13.10's gtk libraries. The global menu that ubuntu has, GTk is not able to use it for its menu options.
Hence, as @bogdan said, either use the command

```
UBUNTU_MENUPROXY= ./smartgit.sh
```

or open up the smartgit.sh / smartgithg.sh in your favorite text editor and add the line below right after the comments in the file,

```
UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0
```

i.e. it should look like

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Normally, editing this script should not be required.
#
# To specify an alternative Java Runtime Environment, set the environment variable SMARTGITHG_JAVA_HOME

UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0

if [ ......
```

Answer (score 1):

The first comment of that bug report does supply a workaround, which for me works. Just start SmartGit like this:

`UBUNTU_MENUPROXY= ./smartgit.sh`

It can be used as a temporary solution until the bug is fixed.